# Pulse amplitude modulation

Tags: modulation, reference-request, books

I am reading from the internet and my professor's course on PAM. This course is not well-organized, and I would like to ask for book recommendations. I know that this modulation is divided into two parts, and the one that interests me is baseband modulation. It is based on sampling a modulation signal and then multiplying it by a pulse shape. What I'm missing is an understanding of the power spectrum and the influence of symbols on this spectrum. Finally, I need to study inter-symbol interference.

Answer (score 1):

For getting started with digital communications, I think Sklar ("Digital Communications: Fundamentals and Applications") and Haykin ("An Introduction to Analog and Digital Communications", "Digital Communications" and/or "Digital Communication Systems") are probably the most accessible. They are very clear and cover the material you're asking about. Very close in second place I'd recommend L. Couch, "Digital and Analog Communication Systems", and Lathi's "Modern Digital and Analog Communication".